# In ggplot2, how is the offset distance calculated when we use nudge_y?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, how is the offset distance calculated when we use nudge_y? Also, why does offset visually vary when I change the size of the Plot pane in RStudio Console. Sharing the code which I am using:

```
# using ggplot2 in RStudio
library(ggplot2)
tab_count <- data.frame(table(mpg$drv))
colnames(tab_count) <- c("drv","count_var")

ggplot(data = tab_count,aes(x = drv,y=count_var,label=count_var)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  xlab("Drive Type (front/ rear/4-wheel)") +
  geom_text(nudge_y = 4, size = 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nudging happens by units of the scale you're on so in this case the label is 4 points above it's actual y value.

Using something like `vjust = -1` keeps the offset constant

Comment: Thanks for the precise response. Would you know how the offset distance is computed by vjust i.e. what is it anchoring to?

Comment: vjust is normally between 0 and 1 to right or left adjust. Not sure however what it is doing exactly when you go beyond those limits